# noexcept depend on noexcept of a member function

Tags: c++, gcc, noexcept

Consider:

```
class test {
    private:
        int n;

        int impl () const noexcept {
            return n;
        }

    public:
        test () = delete;
        test (int n) noexcept : n(n) {    }

        int get () const noexcept(noexcept(impl())) {
            return impl();
        }
};
```

GCC says no:

```
test.cpp:27:43: error: cannot call member function 'int test::impl() const' with
out object
   int get () const noexcept(noexcept(impl())) {
```

Similarly:

```
test.cpp:27:38: error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
   int get () const noexcept(noexcept(this->impl())) {
```

and

```
test.cpp:31:58: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class test'
   int get () const noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<test>().impl())) {
                                                          ^
test.cpp:8:7: error: forward declaration of 'class test'
 class test {
```

Is this intended behaviour as per the standard, or a bug in GCC (4.8.0)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules for where `this` can be used changed as a result of [core language issue 1207](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1207), actually for another reason but in a way that also affects `noexcept` expressions.

Before (after C++03, but when C++11 was still being written), `this` was not allowed to be used outside a function body. The `noexcept` expression is not part of the body, so `this` could not be used.

After, `this` can be used anywhere after the *cv-qualifier-seq*, and `noexcept` expressions  appear after that, as the code in your question clearly illustrates.

It looks like the GCC implementation of this issue is incomplete, and only allows member functions in trailing function return types, but the standard has opened up more than that. <del>I recommend reporting this as a bug (if it has not previously been reported).</del> This has already been reported on GCC bugzilla as [bug 52869](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR52869).

For whatever it's worth, clang accepts the code in C++11 mode.